# One batch at a go

Tags: python, numpy, keras

I have two big Numpy arrays X and Y which I can save and load as a dictionary. In fact, I want to feed this data to a machine learning model using Keras.

Here is the load and save functions:

```
def save_np_data(X, Y, file_path_prefix):
    data = {'X': X, 'Y': Y} 
    file_name = file_path_prefix + '/data.npy'
    np.save(file_name, data)

def load_np_data(file_path_prefix):
    file_name = file_path_prefix + '/data.npy'
    data = np.load(file_name)[()]
    return data
```

Actually, I m facing a problem to train the model because I m always running out of memory. So, I switched to fit_generator instead of the typical fit function.

My goal is to progressively parse the data.npy file (only read one batch from the file at one go).

And here is the batch_generator function:

```
def batch_generator(X, Y, batch_size):
    number_of_batches = np.ceil(X.shape[0]/batch_size) #ceil function allows for creating last batch off remaining samples
    counter = 0
    sample_index = np.arange(X.shape[0])
    while True:
        batch_index = sample_index[batch_size*counter:batch_size*(counter+1)]
        X_batch = X[batch_index,:]
        Y_batch = Y[batch_index,:]
        counter += 1
        yield X_batch, Y_batch
        if (counter == number_of_batches):
            counter = 0
```

Could you please help.

Comment: Sure we can help, but for that you need to describe your problem.

Comment: My first attempt would be splitting the files into small files and make each file a batch.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro I don't know how to read just one batch from a .npy file

Comment: Instead of doing cumbersome splitting, you can use [memory mapping](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html).